# Flask server blog question

Tags: python, video, pi-3b+

I am about to embark on my first experience with Rasb Pi and I want to utilize the code from this blog on how to stream motion JPEG thru a Python Flask server, [Flask Video Streaming Revisited](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited). The blog is written to use with Rasb Pi camera or OpenCV.

Some super basic questions I have... I ordered a Raspberry Pi 3 - Model B+ - 1.4GHz Cortex-A53 with 1GB RAM and I think it has a built in Wi-Fi... Does the Flask server code live on the Rasb Pi device and I would need to configure a Wi-Fi router between the Pi device and a computer/smart phone accessing the Rasb Pi through a web browser?

Ultimately I am hoping to find a simple method to view the Pi camera in a video stream format through multiple devices (smart phone) and I think this seems like the best option to use a Wi-Fi router & flask server. Any tips or help?

Someone also posted a question to this same blog here too:
[Video streaming via motion jpeg, python3-flask, and the camera module](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68648/video-streaming-via-motion-jpeg-python3-flask-and-the-camera-module)

Comment: The Pi B+ does not have built-in wifi.  The Pi 3B+ does.  Remember this is a question and answer site.  One question - one answer.

Comment: Cool it looks like I ordered the right model to include wifi adapter: Raspberry Pi 3 - Model B+ - 1.4GHz Cortex-A53 with 1GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Flask application is not necessary if you simply want to stream frames from the Raspberry Pi camera module to one or more clients. Instead, you might want to look into [streameye](https://github.com/ccrisan/streameye). In comparison to the blog post solution, it also uses MJPEG to compress and stream each frame as a JPEG image over HTTP.

Of course, your clients must be connected to the same (WiFi) network as the Raspberry Pi in order to view the stream.